# Why am I unable to emulate android 2.3.3 when I am able to emulate android 4.1 onwards?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've been trying to test some apps on the android 2.3.3 SDKs, but haven't gotten past the boot screen on every attempt. Trying to run any emulator newer than 2.3.3 works just fine. I don't get any errors when I try to run it, it just stops booting for some reason. Using the -debug all command shows that it starts running in a loop. Attempting to shut down the emulator isn't possible unless doing it from task manager. Do you know what I've done wrong and how to fix it?

I have already attempted changing the graphics, multi-core, and memory settings, as well as booting from cold, wiping data, booting from CMD with/without acceleration. Nothing seems to actually be wrong with the emulator which is why it's so confusing. I'll post the startup logs but I'm not sure if it'll be any help. I can also attach the debug logs if needed, though it's quite long so I'll leave it out for now. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I'm currently running this on windows 10 home edition with an AMD processor. Virtualization is enabled and while I was unable to disable hyper-V from the features panel, I did follow a guide as a workaround for it.

```
VERBOSE | Starting QEMU main loop
VERBOSE | registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '128m'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'ro.config.low_ram' = 'true'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
GVM is operational
VERBOSE | control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-camera: true
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-keyboard: true
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: true
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-touch: true
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-multitouch: false
VERBOSE | Not using any http proxy
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'America/New_York'
VERBOSE | android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_4496.ini
VERBOSE | emulator_window_fb_rotate
VERBOSE | No acpi ini file provided, using default
VERBOSE |  no root specified:
VERBOSE | Path:C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
VERBOSE | Found: 1 adb executables
VERBOSE | Adb: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
VERBOSE | Path:C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
VERBOSE | No acpi ini file provided, using default
VERBOSE | onGuestSendCommand: [0000022B58A6C690] Adb connected, start proxing data
VERBOSE | onGuestSendCommand: [0000022B58A6B970] Adb connected, start proxing data
VERBOSE | onGuestRecvData: [0000022B58A6B970] Adb closed by host
VERBOSE | onGuestClose: [0000022B58A6B970] Adb closed by guest
```

Comment: Why?  2.3.3 hasn't been current in almost a decade.  The number of devices out there in the wild running it is a fraction of 1% of all Android devices.  The tools haven't bee maintained in almost a decade.  Doing this is a waste of time, money, and resources.

Comment: Are you sure that version of the emulator will even run on Windows 10?  That version of Android was obsolete before Windows 10 existed.  4.0 was released in 2011.  Windows 10 was 2015.  I assure you it wasn't maintained.  And the 2.3.3->4.0 (3.0 was tablet only) was a huge refactor of the OS

Comment: Well, "any emulator newer than 2.3.3" makes no sense; hence this is "an Android image"; `emulator` has it's own version numbers, independent from the Android version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) v2 would be required, eg. from May 11, 2017 (possibly with an old version of the `emulator`, also to be installed from the archives). Try `--gpu swiftshader_indirect` for software renderer (or any other non-accelerated mode); it seems to fail at `emulator_window_fb_rotate`.

Comment: This was the answer. Trying on the x86 builds didn't work, however trying it on the ARM builds did. Re-installed the new version of android studio to test if the ARM image would  work there and had no luck. Thanks for the help!